# Существует ли поиск по google, yandex кешу?

Tags: кэширование, поисковые-системы

Существует ли поиск по google, yandex кешу? Сами поисковики не считаются так как бывает что страница не ищется в поисковике, но в кеше она есть.

Comment: ну так собственно поисковики и ищут по своему кешу (ну это не совсем так, но это близко к правде)